# Is there a way to remove punctuation from Persian text?

Tags: python, nlp, data-cleaning

I want to get rid of punctuations from my text file which is an English-Persian sentence pairs data.

I have tried the following code:

```
import string
import re
from numpy import array, argmax, random, take
import pandas as pd

# function to read raw text file
def read_text(filename):
    # open the file
    file = open(filename, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')

    # read all text
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return text

# split a text into sentences
def to_lines(text):
  sents = text.strip().split('\n')
  sents = [i.split('\t') for i in sents]
  return sents


data = read_text("pes.txt")
pes_eng = to_lines(data)
pes_eng = array(pes_eng)

# Remove punctuation
pes_eng[:,0] = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for s         
in pes_eng[:,0]]
pes_eng[:,1] = [s.replace("؟!.،,?" ,"") for s in pes_eng]

print(pes_eng)
```

the code above works with English sentences but it is not doing anything with Persian sentences.

Here the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\persian_to_english.py", line 29, in <module>
    pes_eng[:,1] = [s.replace("؟!.،,?" ,"") for s in pes_eng]
  File ".\persian_to_english.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    pes_eng[:,1] = [s.replace("؟!.،,?" ,"") for s in pes_eng]
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
['Who' 'چه کسی']
```

Comment: It seems that the difference between what you have now and what you want is a subset of Persian characters.  Can you explain what the replacement is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to create a new list containing what you want:

```
new_pes_eng = [s.replace("؟!.،,?" ,"") for s in pes_eng]
```

The line above removes punctuation marks (the ones in first argument passed to `replace()`) if there is any, from your `pes_eng` list items.

Comment: Also, `'\n'.join(pes_eng).replace("؟!.،,?" ,"").split('\n')`

Comment: It's giving this error:

`pes_eng[:,1] = [s.replace("؟!.،,?" ,"") for s in pes_eng]

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: It seems the objects in `pes_eng` list are from type of `ndarray`.  But in your question they seemed to be `string`s (because of `translate` method you called on them). Can you please show some code from where you're filling the `pes_eng`?

Comment: I just edited the post, you can take  alook, and by the way this one with German to English dataset works fine, it is removing the punctuation from both languages , but not Persian :   
   
 `pes_eng[:,1] = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for s in 
    pes_eng[:,1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import re
from string import punctuation

cleaned_string = re.sub(f'[{punctuation}؟،٪×÷»«]+', '', string)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).